# Ghosts in theories of gravity and holographic theories

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, unitarity, holographic-principle, ghosts

I want to understand when a theory leads to [ghosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faddeev%E2%80%93Popov_ghost#General_ghosts_in_theoretical_physics) in gravity. Is there any relation between ghosts and non-linear higher order theories? Ghost is a clasical or quantum field concept?

Comment: Do you know Faddeev-Popov gauge fixing and BRST symmetry for ordinary gauge theories? If not, you should start there to understand how and why ghosts arise. (Ghosts are a QFT concept)

Comment: I suspect that they arise from the quantisation of gauge theories with non-abelian gauge group like SU(2) or SU(3); mainly because I don't recall ghosts being a phenomena of electrodynamics which is an abelian gauge theory ie U(1) is abelian.

Comment: I don't recall ghosts being a phenomenon in the two main theories of quantum gravity - either string theory or LQG - I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 3):

Ghosts also arise in the context of the classic theory through Ostrogradsky theorem. You should take a look at this paper:

> Woodard, Richard. “Ostrogradskys Theorem on Hamiltonian Instability.” *Scholarpedia*, vol. 10, no. 8, 2015, p. 32243., doi:10.4249/scholarpedia.32243.

It's available on [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02210).

The general ideia is that, given a non-degenerate Lagrangian of the form
$$\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{L}(x,\dot x, \ddot x, ...)\;,$$
the associated Hamiltonian is necessarily linear in almost all of the canonical momenta, and the Hamiltonian is unbounded bellow, rendering the system unstable. It implies that non-degenerate systems with higher than one time-derivative dependence suffer from ghost-like (unphysical) degrees of freedom.